# What is the best VB.NET control (standard/custom) for displaying list of files?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, file, custom-controls, user-controls

I'm developing a Desktop Search Engine in VB.NET and I'm looking for a powerful, flexible and feature-rich control for displaying the search results i.e. list of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, the standard is to use TreeView for folders a ListView for files/results.

If you aren't in a hurry, rolling your own using WPF might be interesting. It would be much more flexible, but also a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Windows.Forms.ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control is probably most similar to what Windows itself uses to render lists of files and folders in Explorer.