# Get full quality 16 x 16 icon using Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon and ImageList

Tags: .net, image, icons

Following the directions at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell), I have some code running to extract icons from files and display them in a ListView set to details mode. I want to icons to display at 16 x 16, but when I have the ImageList size set to that the icons that come out look very weird (not sure how to describe it - see attached screenshot).

I've tried changing the size to 32 x 32 and they come out fine, but surely there must be a way to get good quality 16 x 16 icons mustn't there?

http://img165.imageshack.us/img165/4446/badqualityiconscc4.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use 2 imagelists, one for smallimages and one for largeimages to get the best result I think. (The listview has two properties, LargeImageList and SmallImageList)

Edit (found new information that worked when I tried):

This version are using interpolation to get the smaller thumb, should be better.

```vb
    Dim BigIcon As Icon = Nothing
    BigIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("c:\zebra.zip")
    Dim largeimages As New ImageList
    Dim smallimages As New ImageList

    largeimages.Images.Add("1", BigIcon)

    'Fix a smaller version with interpolation
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(BigIcon.ToBitmap)
    Dim thumb As New Bitmap(16, 16)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumb)
    g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    g.DrawImage(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16), New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    g.Dispose()
    bm.Dispose()
    smallimages.Images.Add("1", thumb)
    ListView1.SmallImageList = smallimages
    ListView1.LargeImageList = largeimages
    thumb.Dispose()
    ListView1.Items.Add("Test", "Test", "1")
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work - they're still displaying badly. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried what you suggested in your edit, using the DrawImage method and that doesn't seem to work either - gives exactly the same results. I can post the code I'm using with the DrawImage method if that would help.

Comment: Edited my answer. I think this will do it. If not Im out of ideas.

Comment: Anything that draws the attention from the actual work I have to do is allways nice! ;)

Answer (score 4):

With this [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/System_File_Association.aspx) and the [Demo of ExtractIconEx on PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ExtractIconEx.html) you can write the following:

```
FileAssociationInfo info = new FileAssociationInfo(".docx");

ProgramAssociationInfo pai = new ProgramAssociationInfo(info.ProgID);
ProgramIcon ico = pai.DefaultIcon;
Icon icoLarge = Martin.Hyldahl.Examples.ExtractIconEx.ExtractIconExample.ExtractIconFromExe(ico.Path, ico.Index, false);
```

you have to change the signature of ExtractIconFromExe to

```
public static Icon ExtractIconFromExe(string file, int nIconIndex, bool large)
```

and change the code a few lines down to

```
if (large)
   readIconCount = ExtractIconEx(file, nIconIndex, hIconEx, hDummy, 1);
else
   readIconCount = ExtractIconEx(file, nIconIndex, hDummy, hIconEx, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @HumerGu, I was able to benefit from that as well!

Answer (score 1):

By defaut Imagelist ColorDepth property is set to Depth8Bit, **set it to Depth32Bit**.