# C# File Browsing w/ Checkboxes

Tags: c#

Ok, so this question kind of builds on my last one. I am trying to build a "file browser" but it will do other things.

What I am trying to accomplish:

1. Have a tab dedicated to listing files just like "Browse Files" except I want to be able 
   check certain files and directories.  I also want the functionality of "Browse Files" as
   change location.
2. Get value's from checkboxes to apply elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The question's kinda vague.  We really need a basic implementation to build on or we might be giving you bad advice.

That said, here are some links that might help you get started:

- [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0w5ctby.aspx) control (in the toolbox)
- [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control (in the toolbox)
- [Get File Icon used by Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell)

Comment: Sorry Joel I am new to C# so my wording is more than likely incorrect.

Comment: Actually, it's my wording that's the problem.  replace "vague" with "broad"