# C# Get the default icon of an exe file

Tags: c#, image, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get File Icon used by Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell)

In my program i am reading a directory of files and displaying them as a ToolStripMenuItem

Normally i would use:

```
item.Image = Image.FromFile("icon.ico");
```

But how would i get the default icon that a given exe uses:

```
item.Image = Image.FromEXE("program.exe");
```

Is there a simple way to do it like that?

Comment: From the list of related posts to the right on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell

Answer (score 12):

See my previous question:
[Get File Icon used by Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell)

In summary, it's really simple. Just call `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()`.