# Save the file type icon in DATABASE or in a XML file or

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, database, icons

I am using c#,wpf and mvvm.

In my datagrid every row has in the last cell a ListBox with documents related to this row which I call a period.

The user can add documents to every period.

I want to display for every document the file type icon(16x16) and the document`s name.

The file type icon gives me a bit of a headache.

I am not sure wether I should save every documents file type icon like .DOC in the database because a day has maybe 10 periods each has 2 .DOC files attached thus I save 20 icons in the database which are 19 times redundant...

Most stuff my user will attach are Office file types like .xls,.doc,.pdf,images,zip/rar thats it I guess.

Another but technically more advanced would be to save the unique file type icon as encoded base-64 string in a XML file with the file type extension as key/value pair.

The xml is loaded one time in a dictionary one time at application start up

```
<FileTypes>
<Extension ext="doc" base64string="ff5598sdfusd98fjs9df98sd9f" />
<Extension ext="docx" base64string="ff5498sdfusd98fjs9df98sd9f" />
<Extension ext="xls" base64string="ff9548sdfdsfdfusd98fjs9df98sd9f" />
<Extension ext="xlsx" base64string="ff98sfdfddfusd98fjs9df98sd9f" />
<Extension ext="pdf" base64string="ff98fdfdsdfusd98fjs9df98sd9f" />
<Extension ext="zip" base64string="ff98dfdfsdfusd98fjs9df98sd9f" />
<Extension ext="rar" base64string="fffdf98sdfusd98fjs9df98sd9f" />
</FileTypes>
```

Every time a document comes down the database I check the file extension in the file name and retrieve the dictionary to get the base64 string for the file. I could still somehow implement a caching mechanism for the file type base64 string so I do not decode them every time I get a .doc file...

Maybe you have a quite different/better ? idea, please let me know or make suggestions about advantages/disadvantes of database/xml saving :)

Comment: Why do you save 20 icons in the database? You can create a table FileTypes and save 20 references. And it is better than the xml-file because an application will be loaded faster. Also you can save icons in the folder of the application if you use the approach "one user - one database". It will be easier to answer if you add information about who uploads icons, where do the icons come from, how many users does your application have.

Comment: its a Single threaded app with sqlite database. 1 user 1 database. I do not care if the start up takes 100ms longer if the switching of the periods/documents in the calendar goes fast! I guess a dictionary with key value can be queried faster than a FileTypes sqlite table with doctype/byte[].

Comment: @msfanboy I mean you can create a new folder Images in the application folder and store images there. And in the database store only links to icon files. With this approach it won't be necessary to load all images in memory and it is more flexible to store images as files than to store them as bytes.

Comment: Add the images as resources to the app, then either add a property to your class that stores the extension, or use a converter at runtime to find the extension and select the right image.

Comment: @ALL how can I store images in an application folder if I do not own the images? @vorrtex well we talk about 16x16 pixel images loading them in memory won`t take much time at application startup :)

Comment: @msfanboy The application stores images, not you. When a user uploads an image, the application save them somewhere, and file system doesn't differ from a database in this sense.

Comment: @vorrtex hehe yes of course the app does it I am not the code ;-) Would you still build a cache like an //string == extension like docx IDictionary<string,Image> in my DocumentService so I do not need to do the image loading/conversion 10 ten times when 10 .docx files gets loaded or would you access the app image folder/resource file every time directly?

Comment: @msfanboy I don't think that 10 calls to the local file system take much time. But if you are not sure which way is better, you can write a test application and measure speed of loading of 1000 items with 4 different icons, for example.

Comment: @vorrtex Well I took one .png file with 256x256 px resolution and I fitted them to 32x32 in xaml and loaded them each in 20 documents. I saw no delay in loading them and displaying them via => <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="C:\images\Word.png" /> @Vorrtex I decided now to go your way and use my own free office etc icons and put them in an image folder in my app directory. Then I have a field in my database with the documents .extension like docx,doc,pdf,etc... depending on this string I load the image from the harddisk/my Image folder. No caching needed.

Comment: @vorrtex The filetypes I do not support recieve a white icon with a question mark maybe... as I do not access anymore the file type icon but using my own png files.

Comment: @msfanboy Yes, the Image control is exactly the way which I meant. Also think about relative paths to the images folder and possibility that a user can remove images from the folder (just for fun). A standard icon can help with the second problem too.

Comment: @vorrtex there is still one flaw I have with your suggestion: What if a new MS Office/Open Offce, adobe reader etc... comes out then I have to create new icons and put them in my image app folder. How would you cope with that case?

Comment: @msfanboy If you add an icon after a user uploads a file, you can extract the correct icon as it is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell If new version of any application is released and a user has old version - it is his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid keeping binary images in databases. query and covertion are over heads. the best way for this particular option is to keep all ur pics as resourcess and keep the resource name saved to the database .. u can do tht by keep a enum of the resource names and parse the (eNUM.PARSE) names at onrowdatabound as source binding to cell template of a datagrid row. the cell may contain an image as template content.

Comment: *Always avoid keeping binary images in databases.* @niladridm: There is nothing inherently wrong with storing BLOB data in a database. If the OP knows what he/she is doing and sets up the database properly then there is a negligible performance hit by storing binary data.

Comment: ty, Sir. I always hate it when people say "Don't do 'such and such'..." but don't back it up with anything more than a biased opinion.

Comment: the thing is storing is no poblem but when u query a large amoung of blob records and then pass it on to presentation layer thru a service layer tht is accessed by a DA layer.. transition get heavy when the data grws. and the datagrid of wpf would take longer time to load. its an opinion that i have tested. if u have anything more to add i wud be more than happy to learn.

Comment: @niladridm I do NOT load any byte[] data from database when I load my documents and I have not planned to do that. I do a lazy load when the user click on the open document button ;-) so all I load is the document`s name.

Comment: @msfanboy its fine its natural not to load documents . as in aspx pages for same kind of prob we usually keep two images in cell template hidden and on row binding we can make visible any on of em .. i think this is also possible too on datagrid view on wpf. we need to store 0/1/... repesnting doc type. is it the same wht u meant??

Answer (score 0):

If you have few file types and a huge number of files, its better that you store the file types as a file_type_master kind of database or XML file and load it once while you use it everywhere. But it holds good when there is a good trade off in terms of loading and usage. Or else you can also do kind of caching.

Comment: this is cool... exactly what you suggest I have described in my thread... repatation doesnt get points.