# OPEN a Resource.resx file instead of Creating it which overrides the previous Resource.resx file

Tags: c#, resources, resx

I start my  application from withint Visual Studio 2010.
I add then some files into my application and each file type`s icon like icon from doc,docx,xls,pdf etc are added as String/Bitmap key/value pair to my IconImages.Resx file via

```
private void DumpTempResourceToRealResourceFile(IDictionary<String, Bitmap> tempResource)
        {

            using (ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter("IconImages.Resx"))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String,Bitmap> item in tempResource)
                {
                    writer.AddResource(item.Key, item.Value);                    
                }
                writer.Generate();
            }            
        }
```

When the icons are added to the resource I close the application.

Then I start my application again with VS 2010 and add some files within my document application. The file types are written again to my IconImages.Resx. 
Then I close my application and check the IconImages.Resx file under the \bin\ folder and the previous saved images are gone and I have new/different ones now.

Why can I not say OPEN a .resx file and append stuff to it? Everytime I create a ResourceWriter object with the same name "IconImages.Resx" I overwrite the previous added stuff and thats stupid.

How can my IconImages.Resx file stay alive over an application session without being overwritten by other stuff I add?

Comment: Feel free to interpret "writer" in the name literally, it doesn't know how to read.  The class is not useful in your scenario, it was designed to implement .NET tools.

Comment: not useful in my scenario? Would you please explain what else I should do? My user can add documents/files to a Listbox which shows next to each document a file type icon saved - somewhere and that somewhere is to be discussed...- for now I choosed the .resx file but you say thats not good? So what is a more appropriate way to save a String/Bitmap key/value pair?

Comment: A Windows directory?  A .zip archive?  You haven't at all explained why you want to do this, I can't guess at the right answer.

Comment: Then I explain NOW: My user can add files to the Document_ListBox in the application. At the time of adding the files I get for every file the file type Icon and save the bitmap - icon.ToBitmap() - with the file extension string like ".docx" as key/value pair in the .resx file. When the user restarts the application and loads the documents I want to show for each document the file type as icon which is read from the resx file. I do not want to save the file type`s icon in the database. Its just internal application data. Do you understand now Hans?

Comment: Hmm, you edited. So what you *really* want to do is to cache the icon for a document.  Probably because it is too slow to re-create it when you re-display the listbox?  Is it really?  Windows already does that, Windows Explorer does the same thing.  Are you taking advantage of that?

Comment: NO its not about caching. Read this former thread from me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368046/save-the-file-type-icon-in-database-or-in-a-xml-file-or hopefully you understand better then Hans :)

Comment: I'm lost.  You took the advice of somebody that put "ur pics as resourcess" in his answer?  Just don't do any of this, recreate the image or icon when the data gets restored.  Then tell us what is wrong.

Comment: Yes Hans I took that advice. Well it worked to 99%... I can tell you whats wrong: I can show the icon for each document right when the document is added because I do Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath); but the filePath is the absolute path to a real location. When I have added now a docx document and reload my application the document should display the docx icon again but from where to load the icon? I can not use the Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath) again because in my database I save the filename - not the absolute path to the hard disk.-

Comment: I have have 10000 docx documents in my sqlite database stored as BLOB`s with the docx icon. Or I save the docx icon ONE time on the user`s hard disk as resource.

Comment: Even saving the absolute filepath instead of only the filename will NOT help in recreating the Icon from absolute filename because the user has deleted the document on the hard disk. Its only available in the database as BLOB. Now I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having now a lookup table "FiletypeImage" with the filetype ".docx" and the raw binary data aka blob. This table gets retrieved in my documentService and cached in a static variable. with a Get and Add method which are called by my DocumentListViewModel. Its very fast thx to sqlite :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used ResXResourceWriter, but usually *Writer classes simply write a data file from scratch.

If you want to "append" new data you would typically have to use a *Reader class to deserialise the existing data into memory, then merge/add in any new data you wish to, and use a *Writer object to then write the resulting data back out. Take a look at `ResXResourceReader` to see if it supports what you need to do this.

Comment: first your answer is confusing. Second I already use the ResXResourceReader when checking the resource is a certain file Extension were already added.