# Getting programs icons in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c#-express-2010

I have this code that will grab the names, but how do i get each program's icon?

```
 string SoftwareKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UserData\\S-1-5-18\\Products";
        RegistryKey rk = default(RegistryKey);
        rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey);

        string sname = string.Empty;

        foreach (string skname in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {

            try
            {
                sname = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey).OpenSubKey(skname).OpenSubKey("InstallProperties").GetValue("DisplayName").ToString();
                string Inst1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey).OpenSubKey(skname).OpenSubKey("InstallProperties").GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = sname; 
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = Inst1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware that `InstallProperties` will give you the installed executable (as indeed an installer could install multiple executable files).

If you have a means to determine the correct executable (including perhaps enumerating the .exe files in `InstallLocation`), you could then grab the default icon from that .exe.

For details, see

[Get File Icon used by Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell)

**UPDATE**

The following code is **untested** but should get you pretty close:

```
string Inst1 = registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey).OpenSubKey(skname).OpenSubKey("InstallProperties").GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Inst1, "*.exe")) 
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Inst1, file);
    Icon  result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
    // If result is not null, you have an icon.
}
```

Comment: i am using C# and...how do i do that?

Comment: Added code to show how to search a given folder for .exe files and pull the icon.  Don't recall off the top of my head whether `Directory.GetFiles()` returns just the file name or full path to the file, so you may not need the `Path.Combine` line.  Thanks to @ebad86 for the concise method to get the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Icon  result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
```