# I want to display icon of running process with its name when i am displaying the list to running process in C#

Tags: c#, ico

Hi I am working on windows form.
I am displaying the number of running processes across multiple virtual desktops..It is working fine. no problem in that. Please see the image...[image]

Now i want to display the icon of respective process with name.
So can anyone tell me it is possible or not.
If YES then please give some idea. so i can achieve it.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the icon using `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
     var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(process.MainModule.FileName);
}
```

See: [Get File Icon used by Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell) for more information about icons.