# SHGetFileInfo stops working after many calls

Tags: powershell

After around 3000 calls, SHGetFileInfo seems to stop returning icon handles.
I cobbled together this function that pulls the icon for a file path. I'm trying to use it on a listview control for a directory listing.

```
Function Icon-FromFilePath {
    Param($FilePath, [Switch]$LargeIcon)

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
        using System;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        public class IconFromFilePath
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public struct SHFILEINFO
            {
                public IntPtr hIcon;
                public int iIcon;
                public uint dwAttributes;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
                public string szDisplayName;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
                public string szTypeName;
            }

            [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbSizeFileInfo, uint uFlags);
        }
    '

    $Flags = 0x100
    If (!$LargeIcon) { $Flags += 0x1 }  # Add SHGFI_SMALLICON flag if not requesting a large icon

    $FileInfoStruct = New-Object IconFromFilePath+SHFILEINFO
    $StructSize = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($FileInfoStruct)

    [void][IconFromFilePath]::SHGetFileInfo($FilePath, 0, [ref]$FileInfoStruct, $StructSize, $Flags)
    $global:Struct_log = $FileInfoStruct # logging variable for testing purposes only
    Return [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle($FileInfoStruct.hIcon)
}
```

Here's a quick test script to exemplify the error:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms

$counter = 0
gci c:\windows\system32 | foreach {
    try {
        $counter++
        $icon = Icon-FromFilePath $_.fullname
    }
    catch {
        "Count: $counter"
        "Error: " + $_.Exception.Message
        $Struct_log
        pause
    }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
Count: 3320
Error: Exception calling "FromHandle" with "1" argument(s): "Win32 handle that was passed to Icon is not valid or is the wrong type."

hIcon         : 0
iIcon         : 2
dwAttributes  : 1073742149
szDisplayName :
szTypeName    :
```

I'm assuming I need to do some sort of cleanup, but not sure where to start.
I was previously using ExtractAssociatedIcon and not having any major issues. Unfortunately, ExtractAssociatedIcon doesn't provide small icons (so they look bad in the listview) and it's not compatible with UNC paths.

Comment: From the [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfow) docs, emphasis added: "**If SHGetFileInfo returns an icon handle** in the hIcon member of the SHFILEINFO structure pointed to by psfi, **you are responsible for freeing it with `DestroyIcon`** when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss that. However, I can't figure out a way to destroy the icon while also using it in my listview. *Edit* Actually never mind. I think I figured it out. I guess there's no way to have all the icon handling inside the function.

Comment: `ExtractAssociatedIcon` does return the small icon, and also requires that the calling code releases the resources associated with the Icon handle, calling [DestryIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroyicon), which is of course the same function you call when you use `SHGetFileInfo()` -- If you show the Icons in a ListView (not shown here), you usually add the Icons to a ImageList (still a Win32 Control). You need to dispose of that object, and also destroy the Icons that generated the Images, right after each Image has been created

Comment: @Jimi, are you sure about the small icons? [Another thread I found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37419253/8923626) says otherwise ("The ExtractAssociatedIcon function (and its Ex brother) returns only "large" icons."), and visually the differences are obvious: https://i.imgur.com/R5j7GQo.png

Comment: The difference is not exactly the size, it's the type of the Icon. The associated Icon can be anything that is specified in the Registry. This Icon is usually the colorful Shell Icon, its size is contextual. It depends on user settings and the screen scale. Your ListView also scales along with Screen Dpi changes; or, should scale, if the Process is DpiAware, otherwise you may find the UI a little (or a lot) blurry. Then, it also important what the ImageList's color resolution and Icon size are set to (you control that directly). It's also a matter of preference

Answer (score 2):

Credit to mklement0 for pointing out the need to use DestroyIcon. I've added a ScriptMethod to the icon object before returning it so I can easily clean up after applying the icon.

```
Function Icon-FromFilePath {
    Param($FilePath, [Switch]$LargeIcon)

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
        using System;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        public class IconFromFilePath
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public struct SHFILEINFO
            {
                public IntPtr hIcon;
                public int iIcon;
                public uint dwAttributes;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
                public string szDisplayName;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
                public string szTypeName;
            }

            [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbSizeFileInfo, uint uFlags);

            [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
            
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
            public static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
            
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
            public static extern IntPtr CopyImage(IntPtr hImage, uint uType, int cxDesired, int cyDesired, uint fuFlags);
        }
    '

    $Flags = 0x100
    If (!$LargeIcon) { $Flags += 0x1 }  # Add SHGFI_SMALLICON flag if not requesting a large icon

    $FileInfoStruct = New-Object IconFromFilePath+SHFILEINFO
    $StructSize = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($FileInfoStruct)

    [void][IconFromFilePath]::SHGetFileInfo($FilePath, 0, [ref]$FileInfoStruct, $StructSize, $Flags)
    $Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle($FileInfoStruct.hIcon)
    $Icon | Add-Member ScriptMethod -Name Destroy -Value {
        [void][IconFromFilePath]::DestroyIcon($this.handle)
    }

    Return $Icon
}
```

Now I would use it for example, like so:

```
$form = New-Object Windows.Form.Form
$icon = Icon-FromFilePath "C:\path\to\file.exe"
$form.icon = $icon
$icon.Destroy()
```