# How to extract from exe file the same .ico file as the one used to create this exe?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-3.5

I'm trying to make some kind of SFX: make a program generating a wrapping.exe around another wrapped.exe.

Wrapping.exe embed wrapped.exe as resource and, when executed, wrapped.exe is saved into temporary folder, executed with specific command line arguments and then deleted. wrapped.exe is not always a .Net program and I don't have source code for it.

wrapping.exe should be done in .Net 3.5 to be usable on Windows 7 SP1 and upper without any prior .Net installation.

Wrapping.exe is generated with a C# program using Roselyn in .Net 4.6.

I need wrapping.exe to be visualized like wrapped.exe by explorer. I've made a successful test with an hardcoded .ico file. Code look like this (simplified):

```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(...);
var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription( resourceName: "SFX.resourceName",
                                                   dataProvider: () => File.OpenRead("wrapped.exe"),
                                                   isPublic:     false);

using (var iconStream = File.OpenRead(@"wrapped.ico"))
using (var peStream = File.Create("wrapping.exe"))
using (var pdbStream = File.Create("wrapping.pdb"))
using (var win32resStream = compilation.CreateDefaultWin32Resources(
                                                              versionResource:  true,
                                                              noManifest:       false,
                                                              manifestContents: null,
                                                              iconInIcoFormat:  iconStream))
{
    var emitResult = compilation.Emit( peStream:          peStream,
                                       pdbStream:         pdbStream,
                                       manifestResources: new[] { resourceDescription },
                                       win32Resources:    win32resStream,
                                       options:           new EmitOptions(subsystemVersion: SubsystemVersion.Windows7));
  return emitResult;
}
```

Now I try to get iconStream from "wrapped.exe". I've tried to replace:

```
using (var iconStream = File.OpenRead(@"wrapped.ico"))
```

with:

```
var iconStream = new MemoryStream();
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("wrapped.exe");
icon.Save(iconStream);
iconStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

but I only get a 32*32 icon.

How to extract exactly the same .ico file (including all formats, for example with 16*16 32 bits BMP, 32*32 32 bits BMP, 48*48 32 bits BMP, 64*64 32 bits BMP and 256*256 32 bits PNG) as the one used to create 'wrapped.exe'?

Comment: That's just the wrong way to do it.  The icon gets embedded by the assembly linker into the executable files as an *unmanaged* resource.  Required because the OS doesn't know beans about managed resources.  All the native winapi convenience functions only produce a single icon image from the resource, digging the complete icon out of the file requires a painful pinvoke slog.  Use the managed version of the icon instead with Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream().

Comment: @HansPassant I was trying to extract icon from unmanaged resouces because wrapped.exe is not necessarily made with .Net (my firts use is to embed an InnoSetup exe).

Comment: @HansPassant Made an edit to clarify it.

Comment: My needs are closly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261353/extract-specific-icon-layer-from-file-then-save-it-as-ico-file-with-transparenc. I'll try to use [IconLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16178/IconLib-Icons-Unfolded-MultiIcon-and-Windows-Vista).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy using [IconLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16178/IconLib-Icons-Unfolded-MultiIcon-and-Windows-Vista). The response was already in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261353/extract-specific-icon-layer-from-file-then-save-it-as-ico-file-with-transparenc): Thx to [@Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix)!

With following helper function (of course, extraction icon file name will not be hardcoded):

```
static Stream GetIconStream_ExtractIconUsingIconLib(string fileToExecute)
{
    var multiIcon = new MultiIcon();
    multiIcon.Load(fileToExecute);

    var extractedicoFileName = @"c:\temp\icon.ico";
    multiIcon.Save(extractedicoFileName, MultiIconFormat.ICO);

    return File.OpenRead(extractedicoFileName);
}
```

We just have to replace:

```
File.OpenRead(@"wrapped.ico")
```

with

```
GetIconStream_ExtractIconUsingIconLib("wrapped.exe")
```

This gives us full solution:

```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(...);
var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription( resourceName: "SFX.resourceName",
                                                   dataProvider: () => File.OpenRead("wrapped.exe"),
                                                   isPublic:     false);

using (var iconStream = GetIconStream_ExtractIconUsingIconLib("wrapped.exe"))
using (var peStream = File.Create("wrapping.exe"))
using (var pdbStream = File.Create("wrapping.pdb"))
using (var win32resStream = compilation.CreateDefaultWin32Resources(
                                                              versionResource:  true,
                                                              noManifest:       false,
                                                              manifestContents: null,
                                                              iconInIcoFormat:  iconStream))
{
    var emitResult = compilation.Emit( peStream:          peStream,
                                       pdbStream:         pdbStream,
                                       manifestResources: new[] { resourceDescription },
                                       win32Resources:    win32resStream,
                                       options:           new EmitOptions(subsystemVersion: SubsystemVersion.Windows7));
  return emitResult;
}
```

Comment: **BEWARE**: IconLib only works in a 32 bits process but I was able to use it in a .Net 4.61 process (this library was made for .Net 2.0).

Comment: The answer notes that it is a NET 2.0 assembly and that users might want to recompile/update it.  I dont know if that would allow it to work as `Any CPU` (wasnt part of that question ;) )

Comment: @Plutonix It must be a problem with Win32.EnumResourceNames. In a 64 bits process, callback function crash but I don't have time to investigate and I can cop with a 32 bits process. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are also websites that do this job
https://extracico.com/