# Extract Images from Executable Files Using Managed Code (C#/VB)

Tags: icons, extract, managed

Can I retrieve bitmap information from an executable using managed code only?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to extract the icon, then you can look here: [Get File Icon used by Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell)

If you want to extract resource images then you should clarify your question to state how they're stored in the executable.  Describing how the example exe was created would be useful.