# Is there a way to get the windows default folder icon using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a `listView` with a list of documents. To each of them I assigned an icon, using the following method:

```
private void SetDocumentIcon(ListViewItem item, FileInfo file)
{
    Icon iconForFile = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file.FullName);

    if (!documentsIconsImageList.Images.ContainsKey(file.Extension))
    {
        iconForFile = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file.FullName);
        documentsIconsImageList.Images.Add(file.Extension, iconForFile);
    }

    item.ImageKey = file.Extension;
}
```

I tried to use this method for a folder, but it fails. The problem, as far as I understand, is that `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon` is for files and not folders. So how can I extract the icon of a folder?

Thanks.

Comment: There is winapi function SHGetStockIconInfo for that, but it seems to be complicated to pinvoke it. If I were you - I would create dummy empty folder somewhere, extract icon using that answer I provided as duplicate (that will be default one), then delete folder. You of course need to do this only once on application startup.

Comment: @Evk `SHGetStockIconInfo` isn't complicated at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bet there are other ways, but I think easiest to implement is just use `SHGetFileInfo` win api function over temp folder you create. Example code:

```
public static class DefaultIcons
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Icon> _lazyFolderIcon = new Lazy<Icon>(FetchIcon, true);

    public static Icon FolderLarge
    {
        get { return _lazyFolderIcon.Value; }
    }

    private static Icon FetchIcon()
    {
        var tmpDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString())).FullName;
        var icon = ExtractFromPath(tmpDir);
        Directory.Delete(tmpDir);
        return icon;
    }

    private static Icon ExtractFromPath(string path)
    {
        SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
        SHGetFileInfo(
            path,
            0, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
            SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON);
        return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
    }

    //Struct used by SHGetFileInfo function
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string szTypeName;
    };

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbSizeFileInfo, uint uFlags);

    private const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
    private const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;
    private const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;
}
```

Usage is just

```
var icon = DefaultIcons.FolderLarge
```

It's trivial to add property for small icon too.

Comment: Be careful, you need to delete the icon handle that is returned from `SHGetFileInfo` after you use it to create the `System.Drawing.Icon`.

Comment: You may also want to subsribe on system's icon change event. Whatever it may be ^^

Answer (score 15):

[`SHGetStockIconInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetstockiconinfo) is the correct way to do it, and doesn't require the addition of unnecessary file IO. It's not any more complicated than `SHGetFileInfo`.

Here is an example class structured in a similar way to Evk's class. Some important things to note:

1. When you get an icon handle from `SHGetStockIconInfo` (or even `SHGetFileInfo`, for that matter), the native icon *must* be cleaned up by calling [`DestroyIcon()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroyicon), otherwise you'll create a resource leak.
2. When you create an icon using [`Icon.FromHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle), the object stores the handle you gave it and will use it for later operations. This means if you immediately call `DestroyIcon()` and then try to do something with the icon you just created, it will cause exceptions. You can avoid this by using [`Clone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.clone) to get an `Icon` that doesn't rely on your original native handle.

```
public static class DefaultIcons
{
    private static Icon folderIcon;

    public static Icon FolderLarge => folderIcon ?? (folderIcon = GetStockIcon(SHSIID_FOLDER, SHGSI_LARGEICON));

    private static Icon GetStockIcon(uint type, uint size)
    {
        var info = new SHSTOCKICONINFO();
        info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);

        SHGetStockIconInfo(type, SHGSI_ICON | size, ref info);

        var icon = (Icon)Icon.FromHandle(info.hIcon).Clone(); // Get a copy that doesn't use the original handle
        DestroyIcon(info.hIcon); // Clean up native icon to prevent resource leak

        return icon;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct SHSTOCKICONINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iSysIconIndex;
        public int iIcon;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szPath;
    }

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern int SHGetStockIconInfo(uint siid, uint uFlags, ref SHSTOCKICONINFO psii);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

    private const uint SHSIID_FOLDER = 0x3;
    private const uint SHGSI_ICON = 0x100;
    private const uint SHGSI_LARGEICON = 0x0;
    private const uint SHGSI_SMALLICON = 0x1;
}
```

Comment: a full list of available icon IDs is available here: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SHSTOCKICONID.html

Comment: The link above is dead. 0 Explorer
As of today, this one is not and contains a nice list. https://superuser.com/questions/1406594/is-there-a-reference-for-the-full-list-of-windows-10-shell-icon-numbers

Answer (score 0):

public static class DefaultIcons
{
private static readonly Lazy _lazyFolderIcon = new Lazy(FetchIcon, true);

```
public static Icon FolderLarge
{
    get { return _lazyFolderIcon.Value; }
}

private static Icon FetchIcon()
{
    var tmpDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString())).FullName;
    var icon = ExtractFromPath(tmpDir);
    Directory.Delete(tmpDir);
    return icon;
}

private static Icon ExtractFromPath(string path)
{
    SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
    SHGetFileInfo(
        path,
        0, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
        SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON);
    return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
}

//Struct used by SHGetFileInfo function
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
};

[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbSizeFileInfo, uint uFlags);

private const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
private const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;
private const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).