# How do i get the windows file explorer icon for a file in C#

Tags: c#, windows

How do i get the icon for a file in C#?
i tried using `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()` but it returns a weird version of the image with a low bitdepth (aka the wrong colors but in the right shape)

Comment: refer to this [ask]

Comment: [Get File Icon used by Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell)

Comment: [ShGetFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfow) (should you decide to take that path) will return the System default sizes of the Icons, Small Icon and Large Icon, but not the Extra Large Icon and the Jumbo size Icon. You'll have to get the icon through [SHGetImageList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetimagelist) with either the `SHIL_JUMBO` or the `SHIL_EXTRALARGE` flags set.

Comment: Then, use the `GetIcon()` method of the [IImageList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commoncontrols/nn-commoncontrols-iimagelist) intrerface (it needs to be implemented using its Guid: `46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950`). It returns an Icon handle that can be used with [Icon.FromHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle).

Comment: The `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()` method uses the base Shell [ExtractAssociatedIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extractassociatediconw) method with the `pIcon` argument set to `0` (the index  of the first icon available).